# Better way to truncate an item in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a long list of lists where the first element in a list is a long string and I need to truncate to a shorter string.
I am currently iterating through the lists twice.  Once to shorted the first element and the second to format for output:

```
for i in range(len(prefData)):
    temp = prefData[i][0]
    temp = temp[:40]
    prefData[i][0] = temp

for row in prefData:
    print('formatting strings'.format(*row))
```

Is there a way to just iterate through the list once and include a truncating step in the second iteration?  I want to change the list elements in place and not just truncate for output.

Comment: Can't you just assign back to self instead of doing this odd `temp` dance?

Answer (score 2):

`row` is a list and you can update it without an extra indexing step or temporary variable

```
for row in prefData:
    row[0] = row[0][:40]
    print('formatting strings {} {} {}'.format(*row))
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop is quite a slow process. You can truncated each row on a fly, by reformating `prefData`.

Something like this:

```
prefData = [ [r[0][:40]]+r[1:] for r in prefData]
```

It usually works much faster than for loop.

Comment: @jhpratt I believe it is the [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), not a loop :\ Somehow in python they work very differently.